# copy() php на сервере создает заглушку, а не картинку. В чем может быть проблема?

Tags: php, парсер, fileupload, copy

делаю парсер и загружаю на сервер картинки функцией copy()
Но, почему-то, вместо картинки выводит в браузере заглушку

[image: вот эту заглушку]

Если проследовать по пути на сервере, то картинка там есть и скачана как нужно.
Код для загрузки

```
    $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/../../';
    $img_path = $path."site.ru/img/";
    $img_tmp = "site.ru/img/";
    $this_id = 32324; // уникальный id для картинки
    
$jo //здесь url картинки с удаленного сервера
    
        if(copy($jo, $img_path.$this_id.".jpg")){
            $img = $img_tmp.$this_id.".jpg";
        }else{
            $img = "error load img";
        }
```

PHP Version 7.3.31-1

Я думал, проблема в быстрой загрузке. Загружаю 2-3 картинки в секунду.

p.s. если открыть картинку в браузере, то заглушка, а если проследовать по тому же пути, но на сервере, то картинка есть.

Comment: можете прикрепить пример такого скачаного файла?

Comment: Возможно, файл скрыт так, как сделано это в первой части [ответа на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31471932)

Comment: 1) права на картинку не дают ее читать юзера вэб-сервера 2) как в принципе код решает, показывать заглушку или картинку 3) кэш браузера чищен? Вы в целом задаете вопрос про то, как копировать, хотя тут же пишите, что копируется, а проблема в том, что браузер а не то показывает. По факту в файловой системе картинка создана корректная? Если да, то вы не тот вопрос задаете.

Comment: Возможно, вопрос не правильно формулирую))

Comment: На самом сервере, в папке есть все картинки (корректные).

Comment: а если открыть этот же путь, но в браузере, то выдается заглушка.

Comment: Может Ctrl+Shift+R? :D

Comment: какой код определяет, заглушку выдавать ил картинку? варианты: 1) проверка осуществляется на стороне сервера 2) на стороне клиента. В случае 1 (пхп или хтаксесс) - смотрите права доступа на скопированные картинки. в случае 2 смотреть в сторону кэширования в браузере

Comment: браузерный кеш чистился, не помогло. htaccess на сайте вообще нет. ХЗ кто решает по поводу этого случая. Больше всего, что сервер, но как это побороть....